# Ring theory: Ideals being equal

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Question: Prove directly, without gcd computations, the following equalities of ideals.

(i) $(5, 7) = (1)$ in $\Bbb{Z}$ (of course (1) = $\Bbb Z$).

(ii) $(15, 9) = (3)$ in $Z$.

(iii) $(X^3 −1,X^2 −1) = (X −1)  \text{ in } \Bbb{Q} [X]$

Attempted solution: 
Try to show that $(1)$ is a subset of $(5,7)$ and that $(5,7)$ is a subset of $(1)$

First thing is $(5,7) = 5x + 7y$ with $x,y$ integers. Then by the closure under addition of the integers $(5,7)$ is a subset of $(1)$ as $(1)$ is the integers

Next to show $(5,7)$ is a subset of $(1)$ I try to say if $x$ belongs to integers, $x=5q + 7p, 1=5q + 7p$, then $x=x . 1= x(5q + 7 p)$ which is $5q' +7p'$, which shows that if $x$ is an integer then it's also in $(5,7)$

Comment: Was the down-vote for not writing the maths clearly?

Comment: Even though you shouldn't use gcd computation, it will still help to write, respectively, $1 = 5a + 7b$; $3 = 15a + 9b$; $X - 1 = (X^3 - 1)a(X) + (X^2-1)b(X)$ (without ever mentioning gcd).

Comment: Okay, yes I see. I can see how if you let a and b be the right integers you can get all integers, but I don't know how to show that mathematically!

Comment: No, I meant find (concrete) $a$ and $b$ such that $1 = 5a + 7b$; similarly for the others. (Of course, you get this by executing the Euclidean algorithm to compute a gcd)

Comment: I understand now thanks to Rob and Sam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (i) you have that $1 = 5x + 7y$ for some $x,y \in \Bbb{Z}$. This can be done using the Euclidean algorithm. One solution is $x = 3$, $y=-2$. Thus any integer $z$ can be written as $z = z\cdot1 = z\cdot(5\cdot3 - 14\cdot2)$, and we have $\Bbb{Z} = (1) = (5,7)$.

For (ii), we use basically the same process, but show that $3$ can be written as $15x+9y$, since both $15$ and $9$ can obviously be written as a multiple of $3$. Euclidean algorithm once again gives $x=2,y=-3$.

For (iii), we have that $X^3-1 = (X-1)(X^2+X+1)$, and $X^2-1 = (X-1)(X+1)$, thus $(X^3-1,X^2-1) \subset (X-1)$. For the other direction we want some $f,g \in \Bbb{Q}[X]$ such that $(X^3-1)f + (X^2-1)g = X-1$. We use the same Euclidean algorithm, but use polynomial division instead of integer division and get $f = 1$ and $g=-X$. This gives $(X-1) \subset (X^3 -1,X^2-1)$.

Comment: No problem. It turns out that $\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Q}[X]$ are both examples of principal ideal domains, so any ideal is equal to one generated by a single element. So this same process can be used in these two rings for any finitely generated ideal to get the unique element which generates the ideal. This element is the GCD of the generators.

Comment: @ Sam DeHorty:  do you mean $x = 3$, $y = -2$ in the second line under item (i)?

Comment: @RobertLewis yes, thanks. All fixed.

Answer (score 2):

For (i), note that $3 \times 7 - 4 \times 5 = 1$, whence $1 \in (5, 7)$, so that $(5, 7) = Z$;

for (ii), note that $2 \times 15 - 3 \times 9 = 3$, whence $3 \in (15, 9)$, whence $(3) \subset (15, 9)$, and clearly $(15, 9) \subset (3)$, so that $(15, 9) = (3)$;

for (iii), observe that $(x^3 - 1) - x(x^2 -1) = x - 1$, whence $x -1 \in (x^3 -1, x^2 - 1)$, and that $x^3  - 1 = (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1)$, $x^2 -1 = (x -1)(x + 1)$, whence $x^3 - 1, x^2 - 1 \in (x - 1)$, whence $(x^3 - 1, x^2 - 1) = (x - 1)$.

Call it a wrap, it's in the can, Mr. Hitchcock!

And may The Spirit of Our Lady The Queen of The Sciences, Mathematics, smile upon and shed her blessings on your Thanksgiving Holidays!

Which also means:  have some good fun with math this weekend!

Hope this helps, ALL of it!  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: You have a way with words. Thank you so much for helping me out too. Cheers!

Comment: @ teddyt55:  Haha!  Thanks; it's the lyricist in me peeking out to check the Turkey Day goodies.  Glad to be of service, and thanks for the "acceptance"!  Once again, Happy Holidays.  Best, Bob Lewis

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Your rings are PIDs. Think about GCDs

Comment: I think we're supposed to not use GCDs and do it the show the subset way. What is a PID?

Comment: A principal ideal domain. Every ideal is finitely generated. The way to do these problems is using the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Really you don't need to mention GCD but the Euclidean algorithm works. Indirectly, I think you will be using GCDs. I